# How can I pivot SUM(Premium) by each quarter between two dates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

As you can see on a picture below (Excel), I have two dates: `TransEffDate` and `TransExpDate`. How can I break the premium of `$490` and put it in a quarter buckets?

[image]

How can I achieve the same in SQL?
I have this:

```
SELECT  PolicyNumber, 
        TransactionEffectiveDate,
        TransactionExpirationDate,
        Coverage,
        WrittenPremium,
        CAST(YEAR(TransactionEffectiveDate) as varchar(5))+'.'+ CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,TransactionEffectiveDate) as varchar(1)) as YearQuarter
FROM    PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
WHERE   PolicyNumber ='PACA1000101-00'
ORDER BY PolicyNumber
```

For 1st quarter will be `0`, because `TransEffDate` starts in a second quarter. 
For 2nd quarter we need to find the number of days between `TransEffDaya` and `TransExpDate` which is 365 days , then divide `Premium`($490) by 365 days which is $1.34 per day. Then 1.34 multiply by number of days between `TransEffDate` and end of second quarter (which is 65 days).
so something like that:

```
WrittenPremium/DATEDIFF(DAY,TransactionEffectiveDate,TransactionExpirationDate) * DATEDIFF(DAY,TransactionEffectiveDate, EndOfQuarter) END AS Year_Quarter_1
```

But how can I get `EndOfQuarter` dynamically for each `PolicyNumber`

There are should be some formulas for this purpose.
Thanks

Comment: I can think of two approaches... One involves getting the values back in rows - but it would involve creating a table of quarter boundaries. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Sure. Always worth to try. Quarters are always the same each year. Correct?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following dynamic pivot.

Now, I cheated a bit by dropping the intermediate results in a temp table, but this can be changed if necessary...

By using an ad-hoc tally table in CROSS APPLY the dates and values are allocated correctly via a day-weighted methodology.  In other words, the math works.

```
--Drop Table #TempData
Select A.[PolicyNumber]
      ,A.[Coverage]
      ,A.[Premium]
      ,A.[TransEff]
      ,A.[TransExp]
      ,B.*
 Into  #TempData
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
    Select Qtr    = Format(max(DatePart(YY,D)+DatePart(QQ,D)/10.0),'0000.0')
          ,Value  = (A.Premium/(DateDiff(DD,A.TransEff,A.TransExp)+1.0))*count(*)
     From  (Select Top (DateDiff(DD,A.TransEff,A.TransExp)+1) D=DateAdd(DD,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null))-1,A.TransEff) From master..spt_values ) D
     Group By DatePart(YY,D),DatePart(QQ,D)
 ) B
 Where PolicyNumber ='PACA1000101-00'

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Qtr) From #TempData Order by 1 For XML Path('') ),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [PolicyNumber],[Coverage],[Premium],[TransEff],[TransExp],' + @SQL + '
  From  #TempData
 Pivot (Sum([Value]) For [Qtr] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p
 Order By 1,3'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns
[image]

---

---

If it helps witht he visualization, the temp table looks like the image below.  Then it be comes a simple PIVOT

[image]

> **EDIT - To Fix the Order By QTR - Notice the Order By 1**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Qtr) From #TempData Order by 1 For XML Path('') ),1,1,'')
```

Comment: #John Thank you very much. Its amazing what you've done. The only thing is the first virgin (before you edited) it was returning the result in 40 sec. But it wasnt ordered by `Qtr`. 
 But the new(current) virgin is unfortunately running forever if I need the result for all policies. My source table containing around 30K rows.
Another thing is higher number of Premium - higher inaccuracy per quarter. Like $6630 gives $1177.45 in 2012.2. But in Excel sheet that I have to match is $1181.  But the total for each `Policy` is perfect.  
But the logic is AMAZING!!! Hope one day I'll get there

Comment: @Oleg The CROSS Apply was faster??  I revert the answer then.  Curious, I show much better stats with the join.

Comment: @Oleg Rolled back the answer.

Comment: @Oleg Regarding the calculations.  It is a simple day-weighted approach so math will always work.  cheers.

Comment: @Oleg Just noticed your comment regarding the order of Qtrs.  See Edit

Comment: Yes, if I comment out `Where PolicyNumber ='PACA1000101-00'` it will give me the result for all policies. #John, is any chance to make @SQL display result ordered by Quarter? like `2012.1 2012.2 2012.3 2012.4 2013.1 2013.2...` Because for now it gives me chaotic order. If possible. Thanks

Comment: #John. THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!!! One more thing, what is `master..spt_values` system table does? What was it made for? It contains weird data. 
 Btw, how long are you in SQL? if you dont mind.
Thanks

Comment: @Oleg Using it as an ad-hoc tally table.  All SQL Servers will have it.  If you have a numbers or tally table, you could point it to that as well.  For that matter any table with more than 366 records will do.

Comment: @Oleg  I've been coding for years (Full-Stack) mostly with financial institutions specializing in risk analytics.  As far as how long, let's just say my first computer was an IBM PC 4.77Mhz with 2megs of RAM and a 20MB hard drive ... cost $7,000

Answer (score 0):

Boy that's tough. Here's one way, you create a table with the quarter boundaries in it. You can add dates way into the future.

```
CREATE TABLE quarters(
  lo DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  hi DATETIME NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO quarters VALUES ('2012-01-01','2012-04-01');
INSERT INTO quarters VALUES ('2012-04-01','2012-07-01');
INSERT INTO quarters VALUES ('2012-07-01','2012-10-01');
INSERT INTO quarters VALUES ('2012-10-01','2013-01-01');
INSERT INTO quarters VALUES ('2013-01-01','2013-04-01');
INSERT INTO quarters VALUES ('2013-04-01','2013-07-01');
INSERT INTO quarters VALUES ('2013-07-01','2013-10-01');
INSERT INTO quarters VALUES ('2013-10-01','2014-01-01');
```

Here's one line of policy data

```
CREATE TABLE Insurance (
  policynumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  premium INT,
  TransEff datetime,
  TransExp datetime
);
INSERT INTO Insurance VALUES ('PACA1',490,'2012-04-27','2013-04-27');
```

You can join this with your data table - the join condition is that the periods overlap:

```
SELECT datepart(YEAR,l1) y,datepart(quarter,l1) q,l1,h1,
  CASE WHEN l1>l2 THEN l1 ELSE l2 END AS maxst,
  CASE WHEN h1>h2 THEN h2 ELSE h1 END AS minend
FROM
  (SELECT policynumber,TransEff, 
    CAST(lo AS INT) l1,CAST(transeff AS INT) l2,
    CAST(hi AS INT) h1,CAST(transexp AS INT) h2
  FROM Insurance JOIN quarters ON(hi>transeff AND lo<transexp)
  ) AS i;
```

That gives the overlapping dates:

```
y       q   l1      h1      maxst   minend
2012    2   40998   41088   41024   41088
2012    3   41089   41180   41089   41180
2012    4   41181   41272   41181   41272
2013    1   41273   41362   41273   41362
2013    2   41363   41453   41363   41389
```

You can now do the subtraction to find how many days apply to each quarter.

```
SELECT policynumber pn, y, q, minend-maxstart v
FROM(
  SELECT policynumber, datepart(YEAR,l1) y,datepart(quarter,l1) q,
    CASE WHEN l1>l2 THEN l1 ELSE l2 END AS maxstart,
    CASE WHEN h1>h2 THEN h2 ELSE h1 END AS minend
  FROM
    (SELECT policynumber,TransEff, 
      CAST(lo AS INT) l1,CAST(transeff AS INT)l2,
      CAST(hi AS INT) h1,CAST(transexp AS INT)h2
    FROM Insurance JOIN quarters ON(hi>transeff AND lo<transexp)
    ) AS i
) as x
```

Which gives...

```
pn      y       q   v
PACA1   2012    2   65
PACA1   2012    3   92
PACA1   2012    4   92
PACA1   2013    1   90
PACA1   2013    2   26
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your post. I am unable to test it now, but definitely do that in Monday.
Thanks.